# Ventilated supercavitation formula

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My goal is to build a model SWATH ship that uses ventilated disk cavitators, similar to the Juliet Marine Systems Ghost. To do so I would like to be able to create a 3D plot of speed, cavitator radius and length of the cavitation bubble in order to find the best size for my needs.

I understand that the formation of cavitation bubbles is a complex phenomenon that depends on many factors such as pressure, temperature, and fluid properties. However, I am hoping that there is a way to simplify the equation. Possibly have factors as fixed values in the calculation. Take them as user input in a python or matlab script.

I have trawled through some papers and found some equations that relate the size of the bubble to the cavitation number or the pressure amplitude, but I haven't found any that directly relate the bubble size to the cavitator speed and radius.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may be asking for classified information.

Comment: @DavidWhite No it isn't. I'm just not well versed enough in physics to understand this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2092678216304885